# How to mount media partition for emulated primary only in android

Tags: internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, mount, media-files

I am trying to mount media partition mount point as  /storage/emulated but it showing mounting and media files are showing in /storage/emulated.

but i am unable to find images in gallery, what is mount point to mount media partition for internal storage in anrdoid.

I am using android-5.1.1 (lollipop)

Can you please help me as early as possible?

Comment: What do you mean with **media partition**?

Answer (score -1):

The default mount point for internal storage till Android 5.1.1 is `/storage/emulated/0`. To mount your internal storage manually, you may use the following commands =>

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mkdir /storage/emulated/0
mount /data/media/0 /storage/emulated/0
```

Comment: Hi how can i mount in fstab .i am using 7th partition as media         /dev/block/mmcblk0p7  /storage/emulated/0  vfat defaults  defaults

Comment: The above syntax is correct

Comment: Didn't get your question. You want to edit the fstab file?

Comment: `/data/media` isn't a partition, it's just a directory which is emulated over `/storage/emulated`. Mount command won't work this way.